# Error in PHP code - How to fix?

Tags: php, ajax

I'll get the error

> Notice:  Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajaxx\load_page.php on line 3

This is my full code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

It was working yesterday but all of a sudden it gives me this error. The full code is downloaded from [A simple AJAX website with jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've had a look on that page before but it doesn't help me any further.

Comment: Without your form markup I can only guess that you must not be sending an input named 'page' in your form post.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The found markup can be found by clicking the link in the post. There's a demo to be found there.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors. Folks here are not likely to travel to a link to wade through code that isn't yours.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['page']` does not exits.

In my experience the `$_POST` value is always set so doing `isset("..")` ensures `['page']` is sent. I think 'page' is not been posted. It may be good to do a `print_r($_POST)` and see what is posted.

```
if( isset($_POST['Page']) )
{

  $page = $_POST['page'];

  if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
  echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

  else echo 'There is no such page!';
}
else
echo "Value not posted";
```

Comment: In my experience the $_POST value is always set so doing isset ensures ['page'] is sent. I am think 'page' is not been posted. It may be good to do a print_r($_POST) and see what is posted. Edited above.

Comment: I have edited and put a full example.